# Reinstalling dual boot

Tags: linux

So I have win 10 system in dual boot with deepin. I realized that I'm running out of space in the primary partition, so I am going to wipe deepin's primary partition expand it using a partition assistant and install a different Linux distro(most probably elementary). 
Is it safe to do that directly from Windows? What are the risks? I don't wanna fix windows boot manager and everything, wanna wipe and install in one go.